# Using iziModal's iframe feature keeps using cached URL, not new URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I'm using iziModal (http://izimodal.marcelodolce.com/).
I'm having a problem with regards to the iframe feature.
On first load of the page the iframe option works without any problems.
On my page I have a dynamic URL generated based on button click (I'm using LimeSurvey to present a survey but with a different user token depending on which button you press).
My problem is, after the first click and successful open of iziModal for that URL, any further button clicks do not update iziModal iframeURL to the new URL, but still uses the old (seemingly cached) URL! How do I stop this?
I've tried to manually override the iframe URL, but that simply does not work.
My iziModal settings set iframe to true and iframeURL to the new generated URL (this is done through an AJAX call). I have also set history to false.

What else do I need to do to make sure the newly generated URL from the AJAX call is used by iziModal without having to reload the whole page?

Answer (score 2):

Try [destroy](https://izimodal.marcelodolza.com/#Methods) method before the initializing iziModal instance:

```
function modalOpen($target, url) {          
    var options = {
        iframe: true,
        iframeHeight: 200,
        iframeURL: url,
        autoOpen: true
    };
    $target.iziModal('destroy');
    $target.iziModal(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try cache busting your url. "www.url.com/?oijd="

Comment: I tried that too, I added a parameter with time in msec. Made zero difference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15804883)

Comment: @RohanBüchner yeah, but it could have so don't critique my answer.